# Random number generation in C using Mersenne twister

Tags: c, random

I want to generate random numbers (between 0 and 1) in c using Mersenne twister. My code is as follows:

```
for (i=1; i<=10;i++){
  srand(time(NULL));
  a=rand();
  b=rand();
  c=rand();  
}
```

i.e in each iteration of the for loop random numbers will be seeded with the current time and with this seed I will generate 3 random numbers between 0 and 1. How to do this using mersenne twister?

Comment: There's essentially sample code in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Pseudocode).

Comment: What more info do you need than the Wikipedia answer and the example code it points to?

Comment: How do you figure the random numbers from your code are between 0 and 1? They aren't!

Comment: A good pseudo random generator is completely useless if you only use it three times and then re-intialize it with a low quality source of randomness such as `time`. Don't do that. Read up some good articles about the subject, first.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't seem like a good idea to re-seed your RNG that frequently. Most likely you'll seed it with the same timestamp each time, in which case you'll get the same 3 random numbers on each loop iteration. You should rather seed once and then use that.

A C-implementation of the Mersenne Twister is available [here](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html).

Comment: I am simulating a system. Each iteration of the for loop is one run (or sample) of the system. I want to make the samples independent. That's why I want to seed the RNG with different values in each iteration

Comment: Your are subverting your intent by reseeding the PRNG with the same value each time.  If you are going to use a time, you will need to use something that has nanoseconds of information in it, not whole seconds like `time()`.  Even then, you need to ensure that enough time has elapsed that the seeds are different.

Answer (score 0):

What Sebastian says is accurate, you wont notice any difference in the value of `time(NULL)` between each iteration, the seed will be almost always the same:

> It doesn't seem like a good idea to re-seed your RNG that frequently. Most likely you'll seed it with the same timestamp each time, in which case you'll get the same 3 random numbers on each loop iteration. You should rather seed once and then use that.

But maybe you can try this, and get better results

```
for (int i=1; i<=10;i++){
  srand(time(NULL)*i*17); //Or any combination of operations with 'i' included
  a = rand();
  b = rand();
  c = rand();  
}
```

In each iteration you will get a slightly different **seed** .